# How to make div resizeable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello stackoverflow community I need help with my script. I'm using NicEditor and I'm trying to make it resizeable like text-area. But when I made div: `resize:both` it can be resized in height, but not in width. 
Here is script:

```
    <div style="width: 147px; border-width: 0px 1px 1px; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: -moz-use-text-color rgb(204, 204, 204) rgb(204, 204, 204); -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; border-image: none; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
<div class=" nicEdit-main" style="resize:both; width: 139px; margin: 4px; min-height: 45px; overflow: hidden;" contenteditable="true">
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

What can I do to make this editor resizeable like text-area? Here is jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/JVhpJ/11/

Comment: i can resize both ways in your js fiddle, chrome mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did first is to create a div called `editorcontainer` and inserted the values you used in your html for the container of NicEditor.

By adding `width:auto` and adding `display:inline-block` and removing all the overflow values, the div will now on adapt to the width and height of the children.

Below the example:

```js
<script src="js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

```css
.nicEdit-main {
    resize:both;
    border:1px solid grey;
}

.editorcontainer{
 width:auto;
 border-width: 0px 1px 1px;
 border-style: none solid solid;
 border-color: -moz-use-text-color rgb(204, 204, 204) rgb(204, 204, 204);
 -moz-border-top-colors: none; 
 -moz-border-right-colors: none;
 -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
 -moz-border-left-colors: none;
 border-image: none;
        display:inline-block;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="editorcontainer">
<div class=" nicEdit-main" style="resize:both; width: 139px; margin: 4px; min-height: 45px; overflow: hidden;" contenteditable="true">
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Also below find your modified Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/JVhpJ/13/

Answer (score 0):

Its a lil bit hackish, but this is what I did:

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
    nicEditors.allTextAreas();
    $("#container").children().css("width", "100%");
    $("#container").resizable();
    $("#textarea1").prev().css("height", "70%");
});

.nicEdit-main {
    height:90%;
    width:98% !important;
}
textarea {
    width:100%;
}
#container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g7yypx31/)

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, maybe something like this (main div style: overflow:auto; resize:both)?

```
<div style="width: 147px; border-width: 0px 1px 1px; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: -moz-use-text-color rgb(204, 204, 204) rgb(204, 204, 204); -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; border-image: none;  resize: both;
    overflow: auto;">
    <p>vw v wev wv vw ev</p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried that? please try your solutions before posting answers